# How to choose CSS for two different buttons?

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

```css
<button type="button" class="button-continue button-save frg-button color-green" data-next="#homephone-mobility-config">Choose this package</button>


<button type="button" class="button-continue button-save frg-button color-green" data-next="#homephone-mobility-config">Choose this package</button>
```

```css
<button type="button" class="button-continue button-save frg-button color-green" data-next="#homephone-mobility-config">Choose this combo</button>
```

I have two buttons with different text in it. I am automating the testing. What CSS selectors do I have to use so that I can use it for different buttons? Its for selenium web driver selectors.

Below are the HTML for the buttons:

Button 1.

////Choose this offer///

Button 2.

////Choose this package////

Button 3.

///Choose this combo///

Thanks

Comment: Any reason to use CSS selectors specifically? You can easily use xpath for this.

Comment: You have HTML for 3 buttons, two of which are exactly the same... then you talk about having "two buttons"... then your text below labels Buttons 1-3. Can you please clarify the question so we can understand what it is you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Choose this package']"))`

Comment: This will only select buttons with Choose this package text in it or will it select other buttons as well? I dont want to hard code it, I am looking for  a  common element so I can use this all buttons.

Comment: oh, you don't want a specific button? so like this? `driver.findElements(By.className("button-continue"));`

Comment: When I try to run it gives me error.                                                   uninitialized constant By (NameError)    @driver.findElements(By.className("button-continue")).click